# Sizing a view based on the size of its subviews using Masonry for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

I am using the Masonry project to manage my AutoLayout for iOS and it works great. Love it so far! However I am running into a bit of a problem when it comes to figuring out how views can set size constraints on themselves. Basically, from a super view (the parent view) i want to be able to do something like this on a subview, lets say its called avatarView,

```
[self.avatarView makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.left.equalTo(self.left);
            make.top.equalTo(self.top);
            make.height.equalTo(self.avatarView);
            make.width.equalTo(self.avatarView);
}];
```

Now I realize this probably isnt the way to do it, but, I basically want the ability for the super view to tell the subview that hey, whatever size you have lets use that as the constraint. I am using Masonry AutoLayout in the subview itself, but, all of its subviews have constant size constraints which I would assume would automatically give the subview its appropriate size. I just want to use that!

So far in my experience with Masonry, It is real easy to set a size constraint based on another views height/width, or set a constant constraint as the height/width, but this is the one thing i havent been able to figure out! I know that in standard iOS, devs can use the intrinsicContentSize to give the minimum size constraints for a view, and I am trying to use this, but it does not seem to work. Does anyone know how the intrinsicContentSize interacts with Masonry?

Any thoughts? Anyone experience this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you need is

```
[self.avatarView makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.edges.equalTo(self);
}];
```

Assuming (as you mention) the subview(s) have some fixed or intrinsic size, this will pretty much 'wrap' the subview and use its size.

A side note - if you are setting one property equal to the same property of another view, you don't need to specify it in the latter. In other words, instead of

```
make.left.equalTo(self.left);
```

you can just use

```
make.left.equalTo(self);
```

Also, you can chain multiple properties:

```
make.top.left.equalTo(self);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. Just make sure you set:

```
superView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

And a sample could be:

```
[self.avatarView makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.edges.equalTo(self);
    make.size.mas_equalTo(CGSizeMake(100.f, 100.f));
}];
```

Then the superView's size will be same as the `avatarView`.

Comment: @mafiOSo I was saying about the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` in superView